# Custom Actions when using InfoPath

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-actions

I am using an InfoPath form and various workflows. I have created Custom Actions where the Button Location is on the "Display Form Ribbon". When the InfoPath form is on the DisplayItem form the buttons do not appear. "IE" the "Manage" group is missing. The "Actions" group is still available.

When reviewing the properties of the custom action there is a section called "Ribbon Location (Tab.Group ID)". The default value for it is "Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children" is there possibly a different value that I can type in there to make it so that my custom action buttons will still show up on the Display Form Ribbon when using an InfoPath form?

Thanks,
Sean W.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, custom action is not supported with InfoPath form

This is because of the InfoPath form has a different template than the default SharePoint form , the custom action is only supported on the SharePoint default form.

But there's a workaround that I don't try it :) at [Add custom commands on Infopath browser form ribbon](http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/03/add-custom-commands-on-infopath-browser-form-ribbon/)